# How can I make a start on this ggplot question?

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, bar-chart, histogram

> Write a function `chartCol(df, colN)`, where:
>
> - df: one selected data frame (e.g. mpg, diamonds,or msleep)
> - colN: one selected column’s name (this should be a string, e.g. “displ”)
>
> This function will return a plot (histogram/bar chart) based on the data type of the selected column. If it’s a continuous variable, it will show a histogram. If it’s a categorical variable, it will show a bar chart.
>
> Hint: use aes_string to deal with string names when mapping.

I'm using the following function:

```
chartCol <- function(df,colN) {
  ggplot(df) + geom_bar(aes_string(colN))
  
}
```

However, this only returns a bar plot and I am not able to get histograms when I write that code in this function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would let your teacher know that `aes_string` is soft-deprecated, and it would be better to do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

chartCol <- function(df, colN) {
  ggplot(df, aes(x = !!ensym(colN))) +
  if(!is.numeric(df[colN])) geom_bar() else geom_histogram()
}

chartCol(diamonds, "carat")
```

[image]

```r
chartCol(diamonds, "cut")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: another way to do it is using the `.data[[]]` pronoum: `aes(x =  .data[[colN]])`